How to estimate the time-varying tail-dependence functions of Liu, Ji, and Fan's 2016 Paper?

Paper Title: A new time-varying optimal copula model identifying the dependence across markets
Paper's Authors: BING-YUE LIU, QIANG JI, and YING FAN
Primary Concern: Tail-dependence Functions were provided in Population Format
Paper's DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/14697688.2016.1205208

LIU, JI, and FAN's Tail-Dependence Functions investigate the Upper-Upper, Lower-Lower, Lower-Upper, and Upper-Lower Dependences. Unlike the conventional tail-dependence functions, the suggested methodology has 2 additional tail-dependence functions.
Similar Paper with an Open Access

Paper's Title: Extreme risk dependence between green bonds and financial markets
Paper's Authors: Sitara Karim, Brian M. Lucey, Muhammad A. Naeem, Larisa Yarovaya
Paper's DOI: https://doi.org/10.1111/eufm.12458

Any programming codes for the estimation in R or Python would be highly appreciated.
Currently, the paper shows population format of the tail-dependence functions. As far as I know, these populations equations cannot be used to estimate the respective tail-dependence functions for each copula families. Consequently, If the authors obtained cross-tail-dependence functions (i.e., upper-lower, lower-upper), how does this affect the sample estimation? Will it be consistent with the normal sample estimates that obtains the conventional tail-dependence functions (i.e., Upper-upper, Lower-lower) with varying negative or positive sign to indicate rotation?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Added clarifying questions
